# Why is the Paroches inside the Aron Kodesh in Ponevezh Yeshiva

Tags: minhag, yeshiva-school, ark-aron-kodesh

This is a picture of the Aron Kodesh in Ponevezh. [image: (picture of a unusually ornate, unusually large, gold-colored ark for Torah scrolls, with no curtain before it)]

I have heard from a former Talmid of Ponevezh that the Paroches is inside the Aron. Does anyone have a source/reason for why the minhag in Ponevezh is to have the Paroches inside?

Please cite your sources. 
Inspired by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29821/paroches-on-an-aron)

Comment: Because the outside is so cool!

Comment: would not match the gold exterior

Comment: I've seen shuls where they have a decorative outer set of doors (like the ones in the picture) sliding them open reveals the Parochet, and behind the Parochet is an inner set of doors. Is that the case here as well?

Comment: @Menachem as far as I understand, you open the Aron which reveals the paroches then you move that to reveal the Torah(s).

Comment: there's a shot of the open aron about 10 seconds into the video here: http://youtu.be/-zTqzpnXcmA?t=10s

Comment: I have seen many shuls designed like that. It may be that it is just and asthetic choice

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_15787_193.pdf

Comment: Because it's spectacular!

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because the ark itself is beautiful; it was made in Europe three centuries ago and is so nice that pictures of it were used for [postcards](http://lcdl.library.cofc.edu/lcdl/catalog/lcdl:52270). Because, strictly speaking, there's no real [requirement for the Aron to have a curtain outside the doors](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29821/paroches-on-an-aron), the importance of having a beautiful yeshiva/Aron Kodesh wins out. I have seen several other synagogues which do the same thing, especially ones built more than a century ago.